# session data updating and retriving in yii

Tags: php, session, yii

firstly I have two tables

1) family - stores data about family like familyid,city,homephone,address,email

etc

2) person - stores about individuals like

persontype,gender,mobile,email,firstname,lastname etc

these tables are filled while signup.

After signup,

Whenever user logins all the data from person and family 
 retrieved and stored in session and used anywhere in the website by session.

```
$person=new Person();
                    $account=Onlineaccount::model()->find(array('select'=>'PersonId,EmailAddress,LastLoginDate,FailedLoginCount', 'condition'=>'EmailAddress=:EmailAddress','params'=>array(':EmailAddress'=>$model->username),));
                    $person=new Person();
                    $person=Person::model()->find(array('select'=>'PersonID,FamilyId,FirstName,LastName,MiddleInitial,
                            MobilePhone,PrimayContact,PersonTypeCode,DateOfBirth,GenderCode,EmailAddress', 'condition'=>'PersonID=:PersonID','params'=>array(':PersonID'=>$account->PersonId),));
                    $familyDetails=Family::model()->find(array('select'=>'FamilyID,HomeAddress1,HomeAddress2,HomeAddress3,City,State,Zipcode,HomePhone,HomeFlag,CurrChapterCode,FinanceMasterRecID,Membersince',
                            'condition'=>'FamilyID=:FamilyID','params'=>array(':FamilyID'=>$person->FamilyId),));
                    //                  $session=new CHttpSession;
                    //                  $session->open();
                    $_SESSION['newaccount'] = serialize($account);


                    $familyDetails->firstName= $person->FirstName;
                    $familyDetails->middleName= $person->MiddleInitial;
                    $familyDetails->lastName= $person->LastName;
                    $familyDetails->gender= $person->GenderCode;
                    $familyDetails->dob= $person->DateOfBirth;
                    $familyDetails->email= $person->EmailAddress;
                    $familyDetails->userName= $account->EmailAddress;
                    $familyDetails->mobilePhone= $person->MobilePhone;
                    $familyDetails->registrantType= $person->PersonTypeCode;
                    $familyDetails->PersonID=$person->PersonID;

                    $familyDetails=$this->getMembershipDetails($person->FamilyId,$familyDetails);

                    $_SESSION['familyDetails'] = serialize($familyDetails);
```

Now the question is ,When user logins and in his profile he wanna change the field like `lastname` through update form...the `lastname` is updating but the updated data is not showing after refreshing also it is displaying last data because of `sessions`...when user `logout` and `login` the newly updated data is showing..

how to show the updated data after refresh through session in yii ..
thanks for reading and waiting for suggestions..please help me..

Answer (score 0):

After updating the profile reassign the session values again. Then only you can access updated data every where in the application.

Comment: yes you are write after updating the value .i did unset the sessionvalue and assigned again ..thank you for reply